# OpenGL not on Mac M1 Computers

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

Ok so I am trying to code a game in IntelliJ and when I try to run it I get this. 
[LWJGL] GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR error
Description : Cocoa: Failed to find service port for display
Stacktrace  :
org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit(GLFW.java:830)
jade.Window.init(Window.java:44)
jade.Window.run(Window.java:35)
Main.main(Main.java:6)

I understand that OpenGL isnt in Mac M1 computers however, I am not sure what do to after I install glfw from homebrew because IntelliJ still cannot for OpenGl. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: where would I type -XstartOnFirstThread?

Comment: OpenGL is available on M1. "where would I type -XstartOnFirstThread?" As a JVM argument in the run configuration.